# get constraint issue when I try to use / and sub function together

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

I am trying to form a text with /. here is my cloudformation code:

```
Resources:
  KeyAlias:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Alias
    DependsOn: KMSKey  
    Properties:
      AliasName: alias/!Sub ${project}-${EnvironmentApp}
      TargetKeyId:
        Ref: KMSKey
```

I get a constraint validation error on this line:

```
AliasName: alias/!Sub ${project}-${EnvironmentApp}
```

Apparently cfn does not like / there. However when I replace the sub function with something static like :

```
"AliasName": alias/test
```

Also when I use join as follows:

```
      AliasName:
        - Fn::Join:
          - "/"
          - - 'alias'
            - Ref: project
            - Ref: EnvironmentApp
```

I get the following error:

Value of property AliasName must be of type String

How can I achieve the above and pass the constraint issue? Or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Sub intrinsic function as follows (not tested)

```
AliasName: !Sub
  - alias/${project}-${EnvironmentApp}
  - { project: !Ref project, EnvironmentApp: !Ref EnvironmentApp}
```

Based on the Cloudformation docs for [AWS::KMS::Alias](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-alias.html#aws-resource-kms-alias-examples), you *must* include the `/`

Also you don't need the `DependsOn` in this case since `KMSKey` is referenced in the `TargetKeyId`

Comment: Yes it worked so what is this: - { project: !Ref project, EnvironmentApp: !Ref EnvironmentApp}? project and EnvironmentApp are params I get from user so now I am confused if I use sub then replacement should happen why do we need - { project: !Ref project, EnvironmentApp: !Ref EnvironmentApp}

Comment: I went based on the [Sub documentation example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab2c21c28c56c11). You could also try something like `AliasName: !Sub alias/${project}-${EnvironmentApp}` I think your initial problem was having 'alias/' before using `!Sub`